# Pass values from a freestyle job downstream pipeline job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

On Jenkins, I have a freestyle job which takes user input (release branch and environment to deploy). I want to use these values in pipeline job. I tried to export the user input to a file, read the file, set the values as environment variables, tried to print in the pipeline job. This doesn't seem to work for me. Any inputs are appreciated?

Comment: Are you using groovy DSL to code this pipeline? Or you are creating a pipeline in a graphical user interface?

Comment: Groovy DSL in the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in later versions of Jenkins [JENKINS-SECURITY-170](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170)
that prevents passing environment variables (or more precisely any arbitrary build parameters) between consecutive jobs in pipeline. The workaround is to start Jenkins instance with system property *hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters* set to *true*

Comment: Since you are using groovy DSL, post definitions of both Jenkins jobs so I can have a closer look. You passed this argument on startup, right? like this `java -jar -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true jenkins.war`